# Why should I define permission tag in my android app for GCM?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, manifest, android-permissions

I was reading `GCM` docs and one thing made me ask this question: why do I need to define permission tag in my manifest and than use permission that I defined ?

Here is the code:

```
<permission android:name="<your-package-name>.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="<your-package-name>.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
```

Shouldn't this permission be defined in the service app and I just add `uses-permission`

And if using `permission` tag is needed what the `signature` level does here?

I'm defining a permission and do not let anyone use it but me!

[GCM](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client)

Comment: You are not entirely correct. Signature level permissions can still be used by  the Android OS. And that's where this permission comes in - it protects the `BroadcastReceiver` or `Service` you use to receive the GCM `Intents` so you can be absolutely sure that you are receiving genuine messages and that no other app is sending you malicious `Intents` made to look like GCM messages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The package level permission are required to identify only particular app to deliver the message.

From [docs](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client)

> Your  + ".permission.C2D_MESSAGE" permission
>   to prevent other Android applications from registering and receiving
>   the Android application's messages. The permission name must exactly
>   match this pattern—otherwise the Android application will not receive
>   the messages

For 
**e.g**  Consider these permissions are like phone number and android is the building. There can be too many people in building while establishing a call link but every receiver has it's own unique phone number ,on this base, a call is connected to that particular receiver.

**signature level** : It's to confirm that the application is signed by you mean on your system which has the same `SHA-1` key that you used on `GCM` console. The `C2D` permission will be granted immediately if this criteria matches.

Comment: The part of the documentation you are quoting is maybe a little misleading. The permission is not used so much to identify the correct app, but instead to prevent other apps from sending it malicious `Intents` made to look like actual GCM message when in fact they aren't.

Comment: yeah i agree it will also work in that way too , if i have the key to lock and other don't then i can only get inside the house (receive message) other won't , like i only have the key and only i get to go inside the house and in other way to say this is , other guys don't have the key so they can't go inside house

Comment: @PavneetSingh  can i use this kind of permissions in my App? i mean if i have an app that serves to other apps and these other apps are not signed by me. but they gave me the SHA-1. can i only serve apps that has known SHA-1? or just google can?

Comment: it's totally depends upon which kind of service you want to give from your apps and i guess you don't need sha-1 of other apps. e.g like android inbuilt camera,phone,gallery app , everybody uses it . basically permission are used when you asking for some important part of os or hardware.in this case permission are there for security, for valid a conversation b/w GCM and app. you need to look what kind of operation you want to do so read this [permission types](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html)

Comment: @PavneetSingh Thanks. Yes clients send and receive important data by `AIDL`. and only the apps that are trusted should be able to send these data. wanna know does android support me or i should implement it myself? how do you suggest to implement it?

Comment: @sajad yes you have to do the implementations in your app if you wanna receive AIDL data. there can be many way depend upon the complexity of task like if it is not two way talk then use `Binder` and for more [Read the NOTE prarahgraph in link to know which case suites you best](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl.html)

Comment: @sajad you can thank me by accepting the answer (after a period of time dedicates to other possibilities of answers  )